# Redirect on another page after form submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have 4 pages: register.php, view.php , edit.php and display.php
On view.php i have a form that displays all data from database. 
I have a search box, results of which are displayed in display.php(it displays just one row from database). 
In display php i have a form with edit button for the entry. The edit button redirect me to edit.php where i can change my data. When i save, it redirect me on view.php but i want in display php with saved values of edited entry.
I tried in  but it desnt work. 
The second problem i have here is to keep in edit.php the dropdown option that i selected in in register.php

I;m new in programation and i hope someone will help me in this problem. THX for help.

My pages:

DISPLAY.PHP

```html
<?php
 include('connect-db.php');

$client = $_POST['client']; 
$contract = $_POST['contract'];
if(
$contract = $_POST['contract'] )
{$query = "select * from users where contract = '$contract'"; }
else{
$query= "select * from users where client = '$client'";
}
$result = mysql_query($query); 
echo "<table>";
 
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{ 
 // echo out the contents of each row into a table
  echo '<label>Contract</label><input readonly="true" value=' . $row['contract'] . '>';
  echo '<label>Client</label><input readonly="true" type="text" value="' . $row['client'] . '">';
  echo '<label>Step</label><input  type="text" readonly="true" value=' . $row['Step'] . '>';
  echo '<br><a href="edit.php?contract=' . $row['contract'] . '"><input type="submit"value="Change"></a>';
  echo '<br>';  
  echo "</table>";
 } 

?>
```

EDIT.PHP

```html
 <?php

 function renderForm($contract, $client, $step
 {
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <body>
<form id="base" name="base" method="post" action="">
 <input data-validate="number" value="<?php echo $contract; ?>" readonly="true" id="contract">
    <input data-validate="text"  value="<?php echo $client; ?>" id="client">
       <select  name="step">
         <option value="option1">Option1</option>
      <option value="option2">Option2</option>
          </select>
 <input type="submit" value="Change">
</form>
</body>
</html>
  <?php
 }
 include('connect-db.php');
  if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 { 
 if (is_numeric($_POST['contract']))
 {
 $contract = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['contract']));
 $client = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['client']));
  $step = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['step']));
 if ($contract == '' || $client == '' )
 {
 $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
 renderForm($contract, $client, $step, $error);
 }
 else
 {
 mysql_query("UPDATE users SET 
  contract='$contract', client='$client', step='$step', WHERE contract='$contract'")
 or die(mysql_error()); 
  header("Location: view.php"); 
 }
 }
 else
 {
 echo 'Error!';
 }
 }
 else
 {
 
 if (isset($_GET['contract']) && is_numeric($_GET['contract']) && $_GET['contract'] > 0)
 {
 $contract = $_GET['contract'];
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE contract=$contract")
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  if($row)
 {
$contract = $row['contract'];
$client = $row['client'];
$step = $row['step'];
 renderForm($contract, $client, $step, '');
 }
 else
 {
 echo "No results!";
 }
 }
 else
 {
 echo 'Error!';
 }
 }
?>
```

VIEW.PHP

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
      <?php 
   include('connect-db.php');
   $sql="SELECT * FROM users";
   $result =mysql_query($sql);
  
   {
    ?>

<table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
   <th span style="font-weight: normal;">Contrat</th>
   <th span style="font-weight: normal;">Client</th>
   <th span style="font-weight: normal;">Step</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
   
   <?php
   }
  while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
?> 
 <tbody>
            <tr>
   <td><?php echo $data['contract'] ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $data['client'] ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $data['step'] ?></td>
   <td><a href="edit.php?contract=<?php echo $data['contract'] ?>"><input type="button" value="Change"></a></td>
   </tr> <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
  
 </table>

</body>
</html>
```

REGISTER.PHP

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<form id="base" method="post" action="insert.php">
   <br>
   <br>
    <input data-validate="number" id="contract" name="contract">
                <input data-validate="text" id="client" name="client">
      <select  name="step">
         <option value="option1">OPTION1</option>
      <option value="option2">OPTION2</option>
          </select>
   <button data-validate="submit">Register</button>
   </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use this instead of your edit.php    

 <?php

     function renderForm($contract, $client, $step
     {
     ?>
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <body>
    <form id="base" name="base" method="post" action="">
        <input data-validate="number" value="<?php echo $contract; ?>" readonly="true" id="contract">
        <input data-validate="text"  value="<?php echo $client; ?>" id="client">
                          <select  name="step">
                            <option value="option1">Option1</option>
                            <option value="option2">Option2</option>
                          </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Change">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
            <?php
     }
     include('connect-db.php');
      if (isset($_POST['submit']))
     { 
     if (is_numeric($_POST['contract']))
     {
     $contract = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['contract']));
     $client = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['client']));
      $step = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['step']));
     if ($contract == '' || $client == '' )
     {
     $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
     renderForm($contract, $client, $step, $error);
     }
     else
     {
     mysql_query("UPDATE users SET 
      contract='$contract', client='$client', step='$step', WHERE contract='$contract'")
     or die(mysql_error()); 
      header("Location:display.php"); 
     }
     }
     else
     {
     echo 'Error!';
     }
     }
     else
     {

     if (isset($_GET['contract']) && is_numeric($_GET['contract']) && $_GET['contract'] > 0)
     {
     $contract = $_GET['contract'];
     $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE contract=$contract")
     or die(mysql_error()); 
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
      if($row)
     {
    $contract = $row['baza_contract'];
    $client = $row['baza_client'];
    $step = $row['step'];
     renderForm($contract, $client, $step, '');
     }
     else
     {
     echo "No results!";
     }
     }
     else
     {
     echo 'Error!';
     }
     }
    ?>
```

Comment: it don't works because i have to pass in display.php some information about the entry that it will display, but i don't know how..

Comment: if you want you can send values through url like this header("Location:display.php?id='yourid'");

Comment: I tried to do it but a little problem and i don't know why. i have a cotract - 2341, When i pass  ("Location:display.php?contract='2341'"); it gives me an URL- http://localhost/form/display.php?contract=%272341%27  AND EMPTY PAGE.   So it adds 272 from nowhere.

Comment: try this  header("Location:display.php?contract=2341");

Comment: i tried with edit.php?contract=2341  and it'w geting, but with display, no.

Comment: I found,  i changed in display POST with GET !  You was interested in my question, THX a lot.